# How do I format XML files in swift?

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I am creating xml file using GDataXMLDocument Library. Its creating xml file like below image:

[image]

But I would like to create this file in proper format as like below Image:

[image]

How do you format XML files like this using swift?

Comment: Provide XML as text not image. Additionally it's look like valid xml but not formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I solved this question by myself.

Edit `GDataXMLNode.m` to make it pretty-print XML by default

Open `GDataXMLNode.m`, and find method - `(NSString *)XMLString`

Replace: `int format = 0` with `int format = 1;`

then write code like below in Swift:

```
let document : GDataXMLDocument = GDataXMLDocument(rootElement: rootElement)
let xmlString : String = GDataXMLDocument.prettyPrintXML(NSString(string:document.rootElement().XMLString()) as String)
```

This is working fine.